# Is Codeigniter Datamapper other_field must append _id automatically?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-datamapper

I have a problem with Codeigniter Datamapper when Joining table. I have 2 table:

```
Purchase
purchase_id, ref ...

Stock
stock_id, purchase_ref...
```

I created a has_many relation :

For purchase:

```
 public $has_many = array(
            'stock' => array(
                'join_table' => 'stocks',
                'other_field' => 'purchase_ref',
                'cascade_delete' => TRUE
            )
    );
```

For stock:

```
public $has_one = array(
            'purchase'=>array(
                'join_other_as' => 'purchase_ref',
                'join_table' => 'purchases',
                'cascade_delete' => FALSE
            )
    );
```

But datamapper seems append _id to the column that I wanna join and it be comes purchase_ref_id
and the sql statement becomes something like:

```
...LEFT OUTER JOIN "stocks" stocks ON "purchases"."id" = "stocks"."purchase_ref_id"...
```

Is that anyway to avoid appending _id when joining table in datamapper? thx a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [hard coded behaviour (for example here, but in many places in the code)](https://bitbucket.org/wanwizard/datamapper/src/fa551c5ce93a754334aec09bc53cca29c7ed64b8/application/libraries/datamapper.php?at=default#cl-538) and you can't change it with the current version. I'm afraid you would either have to patch the library's code or change your db schema.